# Existence of one-parameter family of diffeomorphisms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transport-equation

Let $v(t,x): \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$ be Lipschitz with bounded divergence $\nabla \cdot v$. How do I prove that the the solution $X_t$ of the initial-value problem

$$\dot{X_t} = v(t, X_t) , \quad X_0 = id ,$$

exists and constitutes a one-parameter family of diffeomorphisms?

Comment: Take $x'=y^2$, $y'=x^2$. The divergence of the vector field is zero. The maximally defined solution satisfying the initial conditions $x(0)=y(0)=1$ equals $(\tfrac{1}{1-t},\tfrac{1}{1-t})$, where $t\in(-\infty,1)$, and it blows up in finite time. Hence, the solution operator does not constitute a one-parameter family of diffeomorphisms.

Comment: @user539887 That function isn't Lipschitz.

Comment: So, you mean **globally** Lipschitz. In that case, see, e.g., Corollary 2.6 on p. 41 of Gerard Teschl's [Ordinary Differential  Equations](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/ode.pdf) for the global existence of solutions, and Theorem 2.10 on p. 46 of that same book for the $C^k$ dependence on initial conditions.

Comment: @user539887 I'm interested in the proof that each $X_t$ is actually a diffeomorphism. Usually, when $v$ is time independent, the proof proceeds by demonstrating that $X_{-t}$ is the inverse of $X_t$. When $v$ is time dependent, this isn't an option.

Comment: Take the vector field $\tilde{v}$ defined on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n$ by the formula $\tilde{v}(t,x)=(1,v(t,x))$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Incidentally, notice that the original $v$ does not generate a **one-parameter family of** diffeomorphisms (only $\tilde{v}$ does).